# Problem with configurable product images

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, product-images

hopefully someone here can help me out please...

I've added a configurable product with 3 individual colour attributes. Everything is working fine, apart from one colour combination.

If you visit http://newsite.yummykids.co.uk/bugaboo-bee3.html and try selecting any combination, it all works as it should, apart from if you select Black Frame with Soft Pink Canopy, and then try choosing any Seat colour - the product image fails to update as it does with all the others. I've uploaded these in the same way throughout so I have no idea why this is happening!

There are 64 images uploaded in total and it's just these four which aren't working.

One thing I've noticed (perhaps unrelated) is that the colour name needs to be unique for each attribute, which is why I've added 'Canopy' and 'Frame' to the colour names. Can anyone elaborate on this further?

I have cleared all caches and indexes.

Any assistance most appreciated - thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, but I'm still at a loss as to how to fix this! I've checked and checked and all the colours are correct. One other clue is, if you choose a Seat Colour first, then you can view the missing images, but as soon as you click into a Canopy they vanish. Is this a bug? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

when you select black frame, it loads the same picture name as if you first click on Soft Pink Canopy.

Since Magento in the background merges all your simple product images, this should be your Problem.

Comment: I've noticed that if you choose a Seat colour first and change seat colours, that is one way of viewing those missing four images. As soon as you click into a Canopy or Frame, they stop working. I have no idea what's going on. Thanking you in advance...

Comment: Can anyone help on this, please? It's causing so much trouble and I can't move on with rest of the site. Thanking you in advance...

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

Most probably picture is not assigned on pink color. You need to assign/reassign in admin area or where ever you did it.

## Explanation:

Tried to investigate your issue. Most probably you don't have any bugs in code. Looks like you have some issues in your configuration. Let me try to explain why I think so.

[product-media.js](http://newsite.yummykids.co.uk/skin/frontend/intenso/default/js/configurableswatches/product-media.js)

In this file your magento determine which picture it should show you. If to be more direct in method `getCompatibleProductImages` which is near the row 33. When you choose some swatch image magento calculates which image to show. Algorithm is following:

E.g. you have following selection:

```
Frame: Black Frame
Canopy: Off White Canopy
Seat: Grey Melange Seat
```

On each selection it starts search images. All images which refers to each group. And then checks intersection. And in your case near Pink color there no intersection. Why it could happen? It's not file permissions issue, as if you select color black - you can see pink picture. Why it happen? Picture with pink Canopy is assigned only on black color. I checked the code and when you try to select pink color - I got empty intersection. It means that this picture doesn't belong to pink color.